# basic python code for a string manipulation function not working in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write a function in python 3 using Jupyter notebooks in anaconda which will input a string consisting of two words and return True if both words start with the same letter and False if they do not start with the same letter.
For example-
If the string is 'Hello Hosey', it returns True, if the string is 'Hello Jose', it returns False

My code is written below

```
def strin(x):
    l=len(x)
    i=0
    while(i<l):
        if(x[i]==' '):
               pos=i
               break
        i+=1
    if(x[0]==x[pos]):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Please help me and point out what wrong i am doing.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Your posted code defines a function and then quits without executing anything.

Comment: `x` is the index of the space, not the one of the first letter of the next word.

Comment: @Prune He said in the text that he uses `strin('Hello Hey')`

Comment: Use `x.split()` to split the string into words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
def strin(x):
    x = x.split()
    if x[0][0] == x[1][0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Input:-

```
strin('Hello Hey')
```

Output:-

```
True
```